# mySQL fulltext search problems

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I need to implement FULL-TEXT search in a mySQL InnoDB  v5.6.20.
I added on two varchar(256) columns one after the other a full-text index after the table was created via
`ALTER TABLE 'client' ADD FULLTEXT('company')` and
`ALTER TABLE 'client' ADD FULLTEXT('country')`

When I use one column to `MATCH`against a keyword I get expected results.

```
SELECT * FROM client WHERE MATCH (company) AGAINST (:keyword)
```

When I use two column to `MATCH`against a keyword I get `no` result at all.

```
SELECT * FROM client WHERE MATCH (company, country) AGAINST (:keyword)
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that the `keyword` is present in both the `company` and `country` for any records?

Comment: hm - either in company or in country. What do I miss ?

Comment: Your FULLTEXT index must be over both columns, not as two separated indexes

Comment: how to achieve this ?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE 'client' ADD FULLTEXT INDEX 'index_name' ('company', 'country');` - but use backquotes, not single ones.

Comment: Ok, what is the major different to the answer of Tim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting multiple columns inside a `MATCH` will use `AND`, so if you want `OR` (based on your comment) you can try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM client
WHERE MATCH (company) AGAINST (:keyword) OR MATCH (country) AGAINST (:keyword)
```

Comment: hey Tim - this is it - you saved my day !

Comment: @Ben Glad to be of service and thanks for using Stack Overflow.